# Antialiasing 2 tone bitmap in .net without shrinking

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap, antialiasing

Is there a way to antialias a 2 tone bitmap (in .NET) without shrinking an image.  For example, I have a black and white image, and the black objects have jagged edges.  I'd like to smooth out the edges on the "non white" objects without shrinking the entire bitmap.

Here is how I am currently performing my operations:

```
Dim from_bm = New Bitmap(frm.ClientSize.Width, frm.ClientSize.Height)
Dim bm_gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(from_bm)
Dim bm_hdc As IntPtr = bm_gr.GetHdc

BitBlt(bm_hdc, 0, 0, frm.ClientSize.Width, frm.ClientSize.Height, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)
bm_gr.ReleaseHdc(bm_hdc)

Dim w As Integer = (from_bm.Width / 4) ' This is the operation I wish to avoid
Dim h As Integer = (from_bm.Height / 4)
to_bm = New Bitmap(w, h)

Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(to_bm)
gr.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
gr.DrawImage(from_bm, 0, 0, (w - 1), (h - 1))
gr.DrawImageUnscaled(to_bm, 0, 0)
```

I'm wondering if there is some algorithm or library I could use to perform the above, but without shrinking the image above.  The reason why I wish to avoid shrinking the image, is because I can't save the full bitmap to memory, I can only save what is displayed to the screen, and this is causing some problems for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure having understood what you meant but I think that you can set the graphic's interpolation mode by using :

```
graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
```